# how to change the default No of entries showing in Candlessticks chart?

Tags: graph, charts, candlestick-chart, lightweight-charts, candlesticks

I am trying to create a chart by lightweight-chart. I don't know what is the default number of entries showing on the screen. But i want to show only 25 entries on the chart like in this image i want to show only 25 candlestick by default but the user can see the rest of the candlestick by scrolling it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might look a bit hacky, but you can use [setVisibleLogicalRange](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/blob/v3.1.5/docs/time-scale.md#setvisiblelogicalrange) to set any visible logical range (which is range in bars indexes, so it might be something like `[lastIndex - 25, lastIndex]`).